# ROS Robot Simulator

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have XML and CPP files describing a robot I would like to build, but I would like to simulate it before I build it. I need to create an HTML file that will start the simulation of my robot running ROS. I have tried a few simulators, but it doesn't seem like any of the simulators I have tried can do this. Any suggestions?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68098/ros-robot-simulator/) by [robonerd137](https://answers.ros.org/users/5488/robonerd137/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You say you have tried a few simulators, are these the ROS ones and you ahve having trouble with usage, or are you looking for what ROS offers in this domain.

Start by having  alook at URDF (ros way of representing robot models). A good starting point is http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf, them hav ea look at RVIZ http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz and finally Gazebo (the fully fledged simulator used in ROS). Also used for DRC. Links are http://gazebosim.org/.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2